# Como lograr que en una insertar código HTML dentro de una variable {{articulo.texto}}

Tags: html, angular

Estoy tratando de hacer una página web, y quisiera realizar lo siguiente:

Por ej, tengo una base de datos con una tabla ***articulo*** y un registro ***texto***, donde  el texto almacenado ya esta formateado con el código HTML por Ej:

BD      : ***Articulos***
Tabla   : ***articulo***
Registro: ***texto***

dentro del registro **texto** guardo la información con el formato deseado:

```
<div>
<h2><span style="font-family: Roboto,arial,sans-serif;">Este es el
título del artículo</span></h2>
<span style="font-family: Roboto,arial,sans-serif;">
<br>
<!-- aca pongo unos espacios-->
<br>
<br>
Este es el desarrollo del artículo<br>
</span>
<hr style="width: 100%; height: 2px;">Sigo con el <span
style="font-weight: bold;">desarrollo</span> y cambio los atributos <br>
<br>
<br>
fin del artículo<br>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

y luego en componente de angular, lograr que se vea el artículo tal como lo escribi

articulo.component.ts
 {codigo para obtener los datos de la BD}

articulo.component.html

```
<div>
 {{art.texto}}
</div>
```

Y el texto dento del componente tendría que verse  mas o menos así:

```
<div>
<h2><span style="font-family: Roboto,arial,sans-serif;">Este es el
título del artículo</span></h2>
<span style="font-family: Roboto,arial,sans-serif;">
<br>
<!-- aca pongo unos espacios-->
<br>
<br>
Este es el desarrollo del artículo<br>
</span>
<hr style="width: 100%; height: 2px;">
Sigo con el desarrollo y cambio los atributos <br>
<br>
<br>
fin del artículo<br>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Lo que estás tratando de hacer no se corresponde con el propósito de Angular, deberías tener el html en el componente, y desde la base de datos obtener solamente la información del articulo, guardar html en una base de datos no creo que sea muy buena práctica en ningun contexto

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta FederHico, tengo claro lo que me indica y como hacerlo en el componente, solo trataba de darle  mas de "dinámica" al texto, sin modificar el componente. Por ejemplo, tengo un listado de "entradas recientes", donde adjunto los últimos 3 artículos agregados, pero si uno de ellos lleva una tabla o necesito resaltar una palabra, no puedo hacerlo sin modificar el componente para cada caso. Tengo muy poca práctica en ángular, tal como lo indica ud, no es lo correcto , la pregunta ahora, existe una forma de hacerlo sin modificar el esqueleto del component.HTML. Gracias.

Comment: Concuerdo con la observación de FederHico es una mala practica en Angular imprimir el html desde una variable, eso que quieres hacer suena como algo que haría con ajax y php de hace 6 años. Eso que quieres hacer, en angular lo puedes hacer con las instrucciones e interpolaciones correspondientes _*ngIf_, _*ngFor_ _*ngSwitch_, etc.

Comment: @electron66 Te dejo el [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/219367/107347) de una pregunta muy similar a la tuya e incluso podria ser un duplicado.