# Interpretar &lt;div&gt; a código HTML | Angular

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, angular-directivas

Hola buenas a todos los capos, tengo una duda espero me puedan orientar para poder resolverla. Estoy mostrando un arreglo de objeto dentro de una tabla con Angular +2, una de estas variables contiene código html

```
data: {
...
descripcion: "<ul><li><b>asdasd</b></li><li><b>asdasdasd</b></li><li><b>asdasdasdasd<br></b></li></ul>"
...
}
```

dentro de una de las celdas donde tengo esta, las muestra de forma literal, y no genera el código html esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
de esta manera estoy mostrando la data con un `*ngFor`

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of riesgos | orderBy:['+num'] | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }" class="text-center">
    <!-- Número correlativo -->
    <td> <i *ngIf="d.idRiesgo == undefined" (click)="mensajeGuardar()" class="fa fa-bell text-warning cursor" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ d.num }} </td>
    <!-- Descripción -->
    <td > {{  d.descripcion }} </td>
    <!-- impacto -->
    <td> {{  d.impacto }} </td>
    <!-- Probabilidad Impacto -->
    <td class="">
      <i *ngIf="d.probImp == 1" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i *ngIf="d.probImp == 2" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg text-warning" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i *ngIf="d.probImp == 3" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </td>
    <!-- Plan de Mitigación -->
    <td> {{  d.planMit }} </td>
    <!-- Responsable Solución -->
    <td> {{ d.responsable.nombre }} </td>
    <!-- Fecha Solución -->
    <td> {{ d.fecha }} </td>
    <!-- Acciones -->
    <td class="text-center">
      <!-- Editar Riesgo -->
      <i (click)="editarRiesgo(d)" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil text-primary fa-2x cursor mr-1"></i>
      <!-- Eliminar Riesgo -->
      <i (click)="borrarRiesgo(d)" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash text-danger fa-2x cursor"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

El gran detalle del que me percate al inspeccionar el código es que me lo muestra de la siguiente manera

```
<td>
                &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;asdasd&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;asdasdasd&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;asdasdasdasd
                &lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt; 
</td>
```

Como podría interpretar este código para que me muestre las etiquetas HTML de manera correcta? de antemano gracias

**SOLUCIÓN:**
Pude solucionarlo de la siguiente manera

```
<td [innerHTML]="d.descripcion"> </td>
```

Comment: ¿Los datos vienen de alguna parte: servidor, base de datos, archivo?

Comment: @A.Cedano vienen del servidor, de la API

Comment: Pero ¿la API depende de ti o es una API de terceros? Pregunto porque si depende de ti lo mejor sería corregir el problema en la raíz, sin tener que obligar al cliente a hacerlo.

Comment: Tengo al backend al lado esta con SQL 2008 y la data está en ASP 3.0, sabes como podría interpretarlo desde ahí?

Comment: @A.Cedano de igual manera la data de la api me llega asi: descripcion: "<ul><li><b>asdasd</b></li><li><b>asdasdasd</b></li><li><b>asdasdasdasd<br></b></li></ul>"

Comment: Yo no sé programar en ASP, pero seguro que sí se puede interpretar desde ahí y considero mejor hacerlo desde el origen. No puedes delegar en el cliente algo tan delicado como la interpretación de los datos. Recomendaría que menciones tu entorno de servidor en la pregunta y que pongas la etiqueta `ASP`, de modo que alguien pueda orientarte en ese sentido.

Comment: Si los datos de la API llegan así: `<ul><li><b>asdasd</b></li><li><b>asdasdasd</b></li><li><b>asdasdasdasd<br></b></li></ul>` entonces es que en tu código hay algo que hace lo inverso, y que te obliga de nuevo a revertir lo que ya venía bien. Revisa eso, porque estarías mareando demasiado la información, haciendo conversiones y reconversiones innecesarias. Parece que estás haciendo una especie de `encode_entities` en alguna parte, para luego tener que hacer `decode_entities` de nuuuueevo.

Comment: Verifique la data con un console. y lo trae descripcion: "<ul><li><b>asdasd</b></li><li><b>asdasdasd</b></li><li><b>asdasdasdasd\n</b></li></ul>" Lo que si me parece extraño es que me pinta los div literales dentro de la vista y al inspeccionar el elemento me muestra los simbolos  &lt;  &gt;

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor poner el código con el que manipulas la respuesta de la API para presentarla en pantalla? Incluyendo los encabezados del HTML.

Comment: Básicamente uso Angular con la directiva *ngFor voy iterando las variables del arreglo de objetos, puede ser que con los antecedentes que me entregas esta directiva transforme la data, de igual manera aplique un replace para cambiar los valores pero no funcionó, dentro de as cabeceras del html tengo el clásico
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
....

Comment: Yo no tengo conocimiento de Angular, por lo que en ese sentido no puedo ayudarte. Pero algo raro ocurre, además me extraña que sea solo un `td` de la tabla en el que ocurra eso. ¿Por qué en ese y no en los otros ?

Comment: @Elleiton tu pregunta debio contener que estas usando asp, que estas usando angular con la directiva `ngFor`, tu comentarios exponen mas informacion que la misma pregunta. La comunidad te puede ayudar si colocas fragmento de tu api que consultas y la parte donde armas con angular. De seguro angular al detectar que la cadena contiene un html la codifica por seguridad, pero si colocas tu codigo de seguro la comunidad te puede ayudar, Coloque el codigo sin miedo que aqui nadie lo va ha hackear.

Comment: Te dejo un enlace a stackoverflow en ingles donde preguntan como [insertar un html en la vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view) y otro enlace a un post sobre como [preservar el html](http://creative-punch.net/2014/04/preserve-html-text-output-angularjs)

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa no pensé que tuviera que ver con la directiva de angular, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Edito post, la solución fue la siguiente <td [innerHTML]="d.descripcion"> </td>

Comment: @Elleiton te invito a que pases y leas en el centro de ayuda a como [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Muchas gracias @OrlandoDeLaRosa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN: Pude solucionarlo de la siguiente manera

```
<td [innerHTML]="d.descripcion"> </td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar una función que te sustituya dichos valores por su símbolo correspondiente, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$('#test').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var t = $this.text();
    $this.html(t.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm table-hover animated fadeIn" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
    <thead class="" style="font-size: 14px;">
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th width="5%">N°</th>
            <th width="20%">Descripción</th>
            <th width="20%">Impacto</th>
            <th width="10%">Probabilidad</th>
            <th width="18%">Plan de Mitigación</th>
            <th width="10%">Responsable</th>
            <th width="10%">Fecha Solución</th>
            <th width="7%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="font-size: 12px;">

        <tr class="text-center ng-star-inserted">
            <td> 1 </td>
            <td> asdasd [1] </td>
            <td> asdasd </td>
            <td class="">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg text-warning ng-star-inserted"></i>
            </td>
            <td> asdasdasd </td>
            <td> Tomas Pablo Rieutord Valencia </td>
            <td> 05-12-2018 </td>
            <td class="text-center"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil text-primary fa-2x cursor mr-1"></i><i
                 aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash text-danger fa-2x cursor"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="test" class="text-center ng-star-inserted">
            <td>
                3 </td>
            <td>
                &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;asdasd&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;asdasdasd&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;asdasdasdasd
                &lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt; </td>
            <td> asdasdas </td>
            <td class="">
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg text-success ng-star-inserted"></i></td>
            <td> dasdasdasd </td>
            <td> Javier Parga Yavar </td>
            <td> 02-12-2018 </td>
            <td class="text-center"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil text-primary fa-2x cursor mr-1"></i><i
                 aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash text-danger fa-2x cursor"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

En este caso se utilizó `JQuery` para apuntar al `tr` correspondiente con el `id="test"`, posteriormente se sustituyó el texto por sus valores `<` y `>`.

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Creo que hay que buscar más a fondo por qué se origina ese problema. Puede que en alguna parte se esté aplicando `encode_entities`, pues en un comentario el OP dice que los datos vienen correctos desde la API y luego le aparecen como entidades HTML.

Comment: Tienes razón, dí esta respuesta en base a lo que se solicitó desde un principio, una vez que llegaron más a fondo en los comentarios queda más claro de donde se generó el incidente. Igual dejaré la información por si alguien se beneficia de ella. Saludos.